# graph plot out of preview area - kivy-garden python screenmanager

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I am using kivy garden graph api for generating real-time graph using screenmanager. So once the plot crosses xmax, I am completely redrawing graph with new xmin, xmax. But the problem is plot is not starting from new xmin. Earlier plot was not even displayed in screenmanager, I changed 'with_stencilbuffer' in **init**.py file of garden graph api to 'False' in order to show it, but now am facing this problem [please see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVT66.png)